# By default JMS is using HTTP?

Tags: java, http, jakarta-ee, soap, jms

For example I have a simple application and going to use JMS in order another application can take information from jms channel.

By default, when I publish a message to JMS I use HTTP protocol - is it true? 
( for example in java-ee examples )

I have heard it is popular to use SOAP over JMS? 
What are real benefits ?but why over? if soap it is transport protocol and not jms.
jms is just a specification.

Please help me to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

JMS doesn't use the HTTP protocol, JMS is an API rather than a protocol. The protocol used for JMS would be different for each JMS Provider that has implemented the JMS API.

I agree that the term SOAP *over* JMS is confusing as it implies that JMS is a type of wire-level format but it really means the ability to send SOAP messages using the JMS API and so integrating into messaging system (WebSphereMQ, Tibco etc). The integrating into the messaging system is where the benefit will come over SOAP/HTTP as you will get the assured delivery, monitoring, scalability etc that a messaging system can provide.